# Can I switch progress on my account to an account that has Ps+?

Tags: ps4, injustice-2

I have Injustice 2 and I'm playing it on my second account which doesn't have Ps+. Can I transfer my progress onto the account that has PlayStation+ and take that progress and put it onto the one that doesn't have ps+?

Answer (score 1):

No, you simply can't do that. It's not possible to swap two accounts' progress with each other, regardless of PS+ status.

See the responses in [this thread](https://community.playstation.com/content/pdc/us/en_US/pdc-communities/support/games-services.topic.html/transferring_my_ps4-iiVb.html):

> To my knowledge save data is account locked. Meaning a game save can only be used on the account that saved it. You cannot transfer a game save between two accounts.
>
> Save Data is account locked so you cannot transfer save data to different accounts. basically to prevent cheating, boosting, etc on the trophies. amoung other reasons. mainly Piracy
>
> Saved data is owned by the account that it is attached to & it cannot be transferred from one account to another.